# imploding and adding characters to a string to generate a sql statement

Tags: php, sql, string

I received an input from a textarea in this format:

```
value0
value1
value2
value3
```

Now i want to explode this into an array, and implode back to string so that

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`valueField`, `myField`) VALUES
('value0','assignedValue'),
('value1','assignedValue'),
('value2','assignedValue'),
('value2','assignedValue')
```

Where `assignedValue` is fixed.

Here is what I did:

```
$myArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['input']);
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $myArray[$key] = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value));
}
$data = "('" . implode("','assignedValue'),'", $myArray) . "'";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`valueField`, `myField`) VALUES $data";
echo $sql;
```

As the result, which is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`valueField`, `myField`) VALUES ('value0','assignedValue'),'value1','assignedValue'),'value2','assignedValue'),'value3'
```

Also if there is a better way to do this in `regex` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it using implode you have to do:

```
$data = "('" . implode("','assignedValue'),('", $myArray) . "','assignedValue')";
```

A little nicer is:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value));
    $myArray[$key] = '(\''. $value .'\',\'assingedValue\')';
}
$data = implode(',', $myArray);
```

Comment: I added something about my question, but you may not answer it.